# SharePoint 2007 CQWP Limitations:

Tags: 2007, content-query-web-part

Morning all,

I'm using SharePoint 2007 Standard SP3

I'm interested in getting some opinions on the best way to surface content from one part of a SharePoint 2007 site collection into another.  I have four document libraries within a child site that I want to surface on a sibling but the limitations of the CQWP prevent me from doing so.  I believe this is because it's not within the same part of the tree.

So, I'd like to get an wider idea of whay my options are, when it comes to presenting content from one sibling within another, so that I can avoid content duplication.

Many thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 2):

In the past I have used third party solutions (such as Bamboo cross-site web part) to expose information across site collections in MOSS.

You could use custom code as well to expose this information if you have this option (though it will take a while).  For example a custom web part to display documents from another site collection.

Another option is to build a vanilla web part page in the original site collection with the document library list view web part, then embed it as an iframe into another page on the destination site collection. 
This will work best if the two site collections are in the same web application (to prevent cross-site issues).
You may have to do some fiddling to make it display correctly (for example removing nav/headings from the embedded page).

e.g.

http://myteams.site.com/sites/site1/Pages/MyPageWithListViews.aspx
http://myteams.site.com/sites/site2/Pages/MyNewPage.aspx

(put this content as a CEWP in MyNewPage.aspx):

```
<iframe src="http://myteams.site.com/sites/site1/Pages/MyPageWithListViews.aspx">
</iframe>
```